# windows printing document size

Tags: windows, printing

I print same document to same printer using different machines both running same version of Windows (with same service pack).  Hardware is different - one is Dell another is HP

The file size shown in the spooler queue for each  request is  different. What could cause that?

Comment: How different are the sizes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metadata about the document and metadata about the computer that is printing.

By opening the document, your account is set as the last author and other things access date changes.
By printing the document, you might send a slightly different information about the way to print it.

These changes seem to be enough to change the compression result significantly.

I wouldn't worry about those sizes unless your prints are weird or the network suffers from it...